# Angular + ui-grid + Calculate the total from column

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am referring the Angular UI grid page 
http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/105_footer

Sample code:

```
     $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [{
        name: 'grandTotalSales',
        displayName: 'Total Amount',
        cellFilter: 'sumFilterSales:this', 
        aggregationType: uiGridConstants.aggregationTypes.sum,        
        enableCellEdit: false,
        filter: {
            placeholder: 'Search..'
        },
        enableSorting: true
       }]
```

Code for the filter function is

```
 .filter('sumFilterSales', function () {
  return function (value,scope) {
     if(scope.row !== undefined) {
     var netAmount=  scope.row.entity.netAmount;
     var vatSales= scope.row.entity.vatSales;     
     var sum = Math.round(netAmount) + Math.round(vatSales);
     return sum;
    }
   };
 })
```

Now aggregationType does not give the sum of the column if I am using this **sumFilterSales** 
If we removed this sumFilterSales then it gives the summation correctly.

Please let me know How to calculate summation of the column in another way.
Please note I can not remove the sumFilterSales as it does automatice calculation of first two column in to third column.
I want to have the summation on last column in footer.

Answer (score 1):

I know I am late to answer this but for some who is still looking for the answer.

```
$scope.gridApi.grid.columns[column_number].getAggregationValue()
```

You can access the sum for the certain column this way